# how to check if the following function is $A/B$ measurable.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have been working with measurable function etc, but i get quite confused if we look at a function which goes from a propability space to say the borel sifma algebra. For example:

$f: (\Omega,P(\Omega)) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$.

$\Omega = \{((j,k): 1 \leq j, k\leq 6\}$, So we describe here throwing two dices.

suppose $f(j,k) = j + k$. how do we check this is a measurable map?

I thought of taking a generator in B(\mathbb{R}) and checking whether the inverse lies in $P(\Omega)$.

So $f^{-1}(a,b) = \emptyset$ if $2,3,....,12 \notin (a,b)$.

If we have that one or more elements of {2,.....,12} is in (a,b), the inverse is just the union of all sets in the form $(j,k)$ where $j+k = c \in(a,b)$. This is in the power set of $\Omega$, so this funtion is measurable.

Is this the right way to prove that the function is measurable or have i forgotten something?

Kees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your map to be measurable, the preimage of any Borel set $B$ should be in the $\sigma$-algebra $P(\Omega)$. But this $\sigma$-algebra is the power set, which contains any subset of $\Omega$, so your map is automatically measurable.

Comment: So any well defined functiuon between these sigma algebras is measurable?

Comment: @KeesTil yes, that is correct.